# Calling RESTful service using VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm using the following code to call a RESTful service:

```
    Public Function InvokeService(ByVal RESTServiceURI As String, ByVal RequestMethod As String, ByVal SOAPAction As String, ByVal HTTPHeaderContentType As String, ByVal HTTPHeaderAccept As String, ByVal RequestData As String, ByVal NetworkCredentialUsername As String, ByVal NetworkCredentialPassword As String) As String

    Dim RESTResponse As String = ""

    Try

        Dim RESTRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(RESTServiceURI), HttpWebRequest)

        If NetworkCredentialUsername <> "" And NetworkCredentialPassword <> "" Then
            Dim objCredential As New Net.NetworkCredential(NetworkCredentialUsername, NetworkCredentialPassword)
            RESTRequest.Credentials = objCredential
        End If

        RESTRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", SOAPAction)

        RESTRequest.Accept = HTTPHeaderAccept
        RESTRequest.Method = RequestMethod

        If RequestMethod = "POST" Or RequestMethod = "PUT" Then

            RESTRequest.ContentType = HTTPHeaderContentType
            RESTRequest.ContentLength = RequestData.Length

            Using RS As Stream = RESTRequest.GetRequestStream
                Using SW As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(RS)
                    SW.Write(RequestData)
                End Using
            End Using

        End If

        Using Serviceres As WebResponse = RESTRequest.GetResponse()

            Using rd As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Serviceres.GetResponseStream())
                RESTResponse = rd.ReadToEnd()
            End Using

        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        RESTResponse = ex.Message
    End Try

    Return RESTResponse

End Function
```

But I don't know if it must to use the following lines of code:

```
RESTRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", SOAPAction)
RESTRequest.Accept = HTTPHeaderAccept
```

Please help, I need this function to be able to call any RESTful service.
Is there any enhancement needed to call any RESTful service?

Comment: Wouldn't the obvious thing to try is omit those two lines and see if you get the expected results?  SOAPAction at least looks like a custom header property so I would guess it's implementation specific thing.

Comment: But REST service has SOAPAction header?